Regex should not match if a value has a dot
I want to check if a variable is in any of a set of words. For example
'Guava'.match(/\b(apple|mango|orange)\b/ig);

The above does not match, which is correct.
'AppleA'.match(/\b(apple|mango|orange)\b/ig)

This too does not match. Again correct.
'Apple.A'.match(/\b(apple|mango|orange)\b/ig)

This however returns a match, which is not what I want. How do I fix this?
I want a match only if the value is Apple OR apple OR mango OR mAngo, etc.

"This however returns a match, which is not what I want" - What does this mean? Why do you think it wouldn't match? Hint: i makes the regex case-insensitive and b looks for boundaries

Apple.A is not present in apple or mango or orange. It shouldn't match. I want Apple and apple to match. So i'm using /i

But . is considered as a boundary

Perhaps replace your \b at each end with ^ and $?

Note your title "Regex to match if a value with a dot is in a set of words" seems to disagree with the words in the question relating to Apple.A: "This however returns a match, which is not what I want."

Apologies. I modified the title.

Try this
'Apple.A'.match(/^(apple|mango|orange)$/ig)


To check if a string is one of several strings in JavaScript, case-insensitively, you can convert the string to lowercase with the toLowerCase method, and pass it to the includes method of the array of several strings to check against:


console.log(['apple', 'mango', 'orange'].includes('Apple.A'.toLowerCase()));



